# How to find which Google Cloud Project is associated with an instance of Google Classroom?

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-classroom

I'm trying to pull our Google Classroom data into a custom web application via the Google API Client (PHP). I was able to make a successful call using a service account set up in Google Cloud, but the call returned no Classroom data.

I'm assuming the Classroom data must be associated with a different Google Cloud Project, I'm just not sure which one. I don't want to create a service account for every single project and test them, there are too many projects. I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find the answer to the question: how do I find out WHICH project a Google Classroom integration is associated with, so I can configure the API Client accordingly?

I tried looking through all Classroom settings to see whether there was any information about the Google Cloud Project being used to store the data. I tried contacting Google Support, but so far I've had problems getting an answer to my question.

Ultimately I just want to pull the Classroom data into our web application.

Thanks

Comment: Did you grant the service account access? does class room even support service account authorization?

Comment: Yes, there's a service account given access to a specific project under the Organization's umbrella. I was able to query for Classroom data (authenticated successfully), but because it seems to be the wrong project, no data was returned. So now I need to know, "well, which Google Cloud Project actually has the data then?" and I can't find any way to find the answer.

Comment: if no data is returned then it hasn't been granted access can I see an image of where you added access

Comment: The service account was granted "Owner" role as a test, so access to the data should not be an issue. It is able to query the data, but no courses are returned. This tells me the data must belong to a different Google Cloud Project, but it is impossible to know which one.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a service account with google classroom api you must configure [Domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation).  This will allow the service account to impersonate a user on your domain.

```
$user_to_impersonate = "admin@yourdomain.com";
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
```

The service account will then behalf as though they were that person. It can then see everything that user has access to.

Without delegation in place the service account doesn't have access to anything.

Comment: I see, thank you for this information. I do not have permission to configure domain-wide delegation, so I will have to have someone look into it. How is one supposed to know that domain-wide delegation is required to pull Classroom data? I can't find that information in any documentation.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.   I will contact the team and see if i cant get someone to look into the lack of documentation.